# How to pass the data in the input type using php

Tags: php, jquery, css

Hi, I want to know how to pass the data into the input type field; I'm using only $_POST method and also I did not use the database first. Please help.

form.php

```
 <form action="booking.php" method="post">
         <p>
          I want to be pick up at:
         </p>
         <p>
          <input placeholder="Enter Address, Airport, Landmark" type="text" name="pickupplace" id="pickupplace" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" style="width: 260px;"/>
         </p>
         <p>
          drop off at
         </p>
         <p>
           <input placeholder="Enter Address, Airport, Landmark" type="text" name="dropoff" id="dropoff" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" style="width: 260px;" />
         </p>

      </form>
```

in the booking.php

```
<div>
    <p>From</p>
    <p>

   <p>
  <?php

    if(isset($_POST['pickupplace']) == NULL){
        echo "-";
        }
    else{
    echo $_POST['pickupplace'];
    }

    ?></p>

  </div>
```

in the edit_ride.php

```
<div>
   <p>From</p>
   <p> 
  <input type="text" name="pickupplace" placeholder="Enter Address, Airport, Landmark"/>
   </p>

 </div>
```

i want to pass the data into the edit_ride.php in the input type please help here it is,

Comment: Your `<input>` tags need a `value` attribute; that's what will be passed in $_POST

Comment: :/ Can you rephrase the question please?

Comment: Make sure you use `htmlspecialchars()` when outputting data to HTML, or you're opening yourself up to potential XSS attacks, among other problems.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, you can merge edit_ride.php and booking.php, so that directly you can display the values using

```
  <input type="text" name="pickupplace" value="<?php echo $_POST['pickupplace']" placeholder="Enter Address, Airport, Landmark"/>
```

This may not be the only solution, as some time we need multiple pages, in that case you may consider sessions or cookies also.

Alternatively, you can pass the values from one page to another using querystring ($_GET) method also without submit the forms in internal pages.

Comment: is there a way for that i tried using the value="<?php echo $_POST['pickupplace']" it says undefined index...pls help

Comment: you need to submit to the edit_ride.php, so that you can access.

Answer (score 0):

why are you specifying the form action booking.php if you need to submit your data on edit ride.php

so first of all change the form action to edit_ride.php and then recieve the data in your textbox as following on the page edit_ride.php

```
 <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['pickupplace'])) echo $_REQUEST['pickupplace']; ?>" name="pickupplace" placeholder="Enter Address, Airport, Landmark"/>
```

Comment: im specifying from booking.php i will get the data and put it on the input type which is the edit_ride.php. i tried your code it will not pass .pls help

Comment: i did that because in the form page when the user input the textbox it will pass to the booking page then all i want is to pass the data also to the edit page which is in the input type...how to do that?